# HTML regex pattern gives an error "Invalid escape"

Tags: html, regex

I have an input element with a pattern that was validated with https://regex101.com/ and others.

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control text-center" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\!\&quot;\§\$\%\&amp;\/\|\(\)\=\?\´\`\*\+\-\_\#\.\:\,\;\@\~\€\^\°\<\>\\]).{8,}" required="">
```

But there's an error in the developer console. How to properly escape the pattern?

```js
Pattern attribute value  
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\!\"\§\$\%\&\/\|\(\)\=\?\´\`\*\+\-\_\#\.\:\,\;\@\~\€\^\°\<\>\\]).{8,}
> is not a valid regular expression:
>Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression:   
>/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\!\"\§\$\%\&\/\|\(\)\=\?\´\`\*\+\-\_\#\.\:\,\;\@\~\€\^\°\<\>\\]).{8,}/  
: Invalid escape
```

Comment: You do not need to escape _every_ character, just ones that has special meaning in regex

Comment: that was validated with https://regex101.com/ and others. ... sure?

Comment: Yes, it has been validated. E.g. the test string Test123abc/AA shows a match. 
Or do you get different results?

Comment: Did anything work for you or do you need more help with this?

Answer (score 0):

**update: try this** wrap your pattern in single quote instead of double quotes.

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control text-center" pattern='(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[!"\§$%&\/|()=?\´`*+-_#.:,;@~\€^\°<>]).{8,}' required="">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yhj4bu1k/

Comment: With that regex I also get an error: Pattern attribute value (?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[!"\§$%&\/|()=?\´`*+-_#.:,;@~\€^\°<>\]).{8,} is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?=.\d)(?=.[a-z])(?=.[A-Z])(?=.[!"\§$%&\/|()=?\´`*+-_#.:,;@~\€^\°<>\]).{8,}/: Invalid escape

Comment: What did you change? It is impossible to guess, also you can make a stacksnippet here instead of a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape only those chars that need escaping:

```css
input:valid {
  color: navy
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input
    type="password"
    name="password"
    id="password"
    class="form-control text-center"
    pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!&quot;§$%&amp;/|()=?´`*+_#.:,;@~€^°<>\\-]).{8,}"
    required=""
>
```

**What did I do?**

Removed unnecessary escape symbols at the following chars: `\!`, `\&`, `\§`, `\$`, `\%`, `\/`, `\|`, `\(`, `\)`, `\=`, `\?`, `\´`, `` \` ``, `\*`, `\+`, `\-` (**note** that this hyphen is moved to the end of the character class where it needs no escaping), `\_`, `\#`, `\.`, `\:`, `\,`, `\;`, `\@`, `\~`, `\€`, `\^`, `\°`, `\<`, `\>`.

Note that `^` does not need escaping as it is not at the start of the character class. `\\` is escaped correctly in your regex.